# how to bind popup page button to viewmodel command property in xamarin forms

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms

I'm new to MVVM and xamarin forms. I want to implement custom popup in mvvm and following is my code 
My Viewmodel is:

```
public class PopupVM
{
 public ICommand CancelCommand => new Command(async () =>{await 
 Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync();});
}
```

My Popuppage Xaml:`

```
<pages:PopupPage.Animation>
    <animations:ScaleAnimation DurationIn="400"
    DurationOut="300"
    EasingIn="SinOut"
    EasingOut="SinIn"
    HasBackgroundAnimation="True"
    PositionIn="Center"
    PositionOut="Center"
    ScaleIn="1.2"
    ScaleOut="0.8" />
</pages:PopupPage.Animation>

<Grid Margin="12"
Padding="24"
BackgroundColor="White"
HorizontalOptions="Center"
VerticalOptions="Center">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <Picker Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <Picker.Items>
            <x:String>....</x:String>
            </Picker.Items>
        </Picker>

    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <Label Text="A"/>**strong text**
            <Picker>
            <Picker.Items>
            <x:String>Item1</x:String>
            <x:String>Item2</x:String>
            <x:String>Item3</x:String>
            </Picker.Items>
            </Picker>
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <Label Text="B"/>
            <Picker>
            <Picker.Items>
            <x:String>....</x:String>
            </Picker.Items>
            </Picker>
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <Label Text="C"/>
            <Picker>
            <Picker.Items>
            <x:String>....</x:String>
            </Picker.Items>
            </Picker>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
        <Button Text="Ok"/>
        <Button Text="Cancel" x:Name="cnclBtn" />
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

**My Popupxaml.cs page is:**

```
public partial class MyPopupPage 
{
static PopupVM vm;
public MyPopupPage ()
{
    InitializeComponent ();

    if (vm==null)
    { vm = new PopupVM(); }
    BindingContext = vm;
}
}
```

I'm not getting where im making mistake. and also i need custom popup not the default display alert

Comment: What is `pages:PopupPage` exactly are you using some pop-up plugin?

Comment: Please elaborate your question before its closed by someone

Comment: do you want to binding the CancelCommand  to Button which named cnclBtn ?

Answer (score -1):

```
<Button Text="Cancel" x:Name="cnclBtn" Command="{binding CancelCommand}" />
```

For more info with commands and binding  go to [this](https://blog.xamarin.com/simplifying-events-with-commanding/)

Comment: I tried it. It doesn't work in this cuz class MyPopupPage  doesnt inherit view or page.